# Getting error called constructor has been deprecated

Tags: c#, wpf

When i changed my **.net target from framework 4.5 to framework 4.0**.
i am getting an error in one line `RUN`>>> `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
                                    PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1(strPrint);
                                    });`

What could be the reason for this??

My code snippet:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string filePath = image_print();
        // MessageBox.Show(filePath, "path");
        string newFilePath = image_print();
        string strText = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(newFilePath))
        {
            strText = stream.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Close();
        }
        string strPrint = strText + Print_image();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strPrint) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(img_path.Text))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            sendfile.Image splash = new sendfile.Image();
            this.Hide();
            splash.Show();
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
                PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1(strPrint);
            });        //<<< here i am getting error in RUN         
            splash.FormClosed += delegate {
                System.IO.File.Delete(newFilePath);
                this.Show();
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the actual error message produced.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx just Net4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) does not exist in .NET 4.0. You need to use [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true):

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1(strPrint);
});
```

Comment: While you're right, that won't produce deprecated error message. Let OP update the post

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes, true, but I guessed the OP e.g. misread the error (as it makes much more sense this way). As soon as the OP updates her question I will also adapt my answer if needed...